# How to draw a line at specific angle using CustomPainter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-custompainter

Please help me to realize is it possible to draw line using CustomPainter at specific angle?
I want to draw Koch curve and can't understand how to rotate two middle segments by 60°.
Thank you in advance!